# Firing a trigger when stored procedure execute

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have stored procedure, which (on some conditions) insert data in my table, this stored procedure will be call from application each time when my window opens. SQL Profiler shows it like below

```
exec TEST.dbo.spInsertRecords @parameter
```

Now what I want is to fire a trigger whenever this stored procedure will be call to execute.
Is it possible? If yes please share the syntax example.

Comment: A trigger will fire if its triggering condition occurs - an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on that table the trigger is associated with. You cannot manually "fire" a trigger. ... if you have an `INSERT` trigger on that table, and your stored procedure does in fact insert a row (or multiple rows), then that trigger will fire.

Comment: Thanks marc_s, what if stored procedure will execute but not insert record in table? also can I pick the parameter passed to this stored procedure?

Comment: the `INSERT` trigger **only** fires if there's an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are set on tables, if you really need something triggered upon calling your procedure (i honestly cannot see why since you shall be able to modify the procedure to do whatever behaviour you'd want), add some dummy table (a log table ?) , create your trigger on that table (on insert for example), and "trigger" the trigger inside your procedure (insert a row).

Comment: ok, let me explain it little more. I am customizing Microsoft Dynamics GP window, this stored procedure is not mine but it's GP stored procedure, it insert data in table some time and some time not. In GP we don't have source code so we usually use triggers, both database triggers and application triggers.This stored procedure have parameter which I want to pick whenever this stored procedure will call. So I can not set trigger on stored procedure? Will it work if I use insert trigger, keeping this in mind that insert don't occur always?

Comment: couldn't you wrap it ? renaming it and making another with the same name (a wrapper) that calls the original one, and add whatever code in your wrapper ?

Comment: :( Sadly not in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If the trigger is expected to execute some code, for example writing record into a log.

1. Write the code directly into the procedure.
2. If you want to execute universal code before or after all procedures, write the code in the place where the procedure is executed.

For example in PHP:

odbc_exec("execute my_trigger_before '$procedure_name' @parameters;
execute $procedure_name @parameters;
execute my_trigger_after '$procedure_name' @parameters;")